# Can Flyway or LiquiBase diff between current database and latest migration?

Tags: liquibase, flyway

I would like to keep a DB centric development process, where the DB and it's data are king. I want to iterate changes in the DB first, playing in the DB tool.

Once I'm happy with the schema changes, I then move to the Java side and would love to use DB migrations to keep everything in sync.

Given the above, is there anything I can do to enable iterating in the DB and then extracting migrations. I need to repeat the process throughout the project lifecycle. Is there a tool to diff between the current DB state and the latest migration?

I'd prefer the SQL centricity of Flyway, but I've used LiquiBase before and I'd use it if it enables my workflow.

UPDATE: of course I should ask if there's some other process I could do? I could run 2 DB's, 1 managed by Flyway/LiquiBase and the other my playpen and do some kind of diff between them.

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase cannot do a "diff" between the changelog file and a database, but it CAN do an "updateSql" command which will output the SQL needed to migrate the database from the current state to what the changelog expects without actually making any changes.

For the workflow you are looking at, what works best is to make the changes to your database and run the diffChangeLog between your updated database and a separately database freshly updated from the starting changelog. [Datical](http://datical.com/) has some enhancements on top of Liquibase to better support this type of workflow.

However, I do tend to recommend iterating your changes in the changelog file itself: append a changeSet, run liquibase update, make sure your change is good, roll it back and try something different if not, otherwise repeat.

By starting the changes in the changelog, you know that the changes that will eventually be applied are exactly the changes you did. Any diff-based operation will try to recover what you originally did, but may not always be exactly right.

Note: Liquibase does support [formatted sql](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html) changelog files if you prefer writing SQL rather than XML, JSON or YAML.